# how to calculate component of array while using tensorlflow

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, keras

From my network, I can get a tensor with shape(21, 3) in the middle of network. 
Before I feed the tensor to next network, I need to calculate it. 
For example, I need to subtract each component by specific value in the tensor.
If the value of
`tensor[10, 0] = x, tensor[10, 1] = y, tensor[10, 2] = z
tensor[:, 0] = tensor[:, 0] - x 
tensor[:, 1] = tensor[:, 1] - y 
tensor[:, 2] = tensor[:, 2] - z`

and also need to normalize it like

`tensor[10, 0] - tensor[0, 0] = a, 
tensor[10, 1] - tensor[0, 1] = b, 
tensor[10, 2] - tensor[0, 2] = c
tensor = tensor / sqrt(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)`

is there any way I can calculate the tensor and feed it to the rest of network again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute a tensor of shape [1,3] with values [tensor[10,0], tensor[10,1], tensor[10,2]] as follows: (there are other ways)

```
s = tf.concat([tf.reshape(tensor[10,0], shape=[1,1]), tf.reshape(tensor[10,1], shape=[1,1]), tf.reshape(tensor[10,2], shape=[1,1])], axis=1)
```

Now you can subtract `s` from `tensor`:

```
tensor2 = tensor - s
```

You will get that the values are updated to `tensor[:, 0] = tensor[:, 0] - x` etc. using broadcasting.

For the normalisation, you can just directly compute it as follows:

```
tensor3 = tensor2 / tf.sqrt(tf.square(tensor[10,0] - tensor[0,0]) + tf.square(tensor[10,1] - tensor[0,1]) + tf.square(tensor[10,2] - tensor[0,2]))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but do you know the same way but what if i have batch tensor (32, 21, 3)?

Comment: I solved this problem with using 'for' state! If there is better way, it will be my pleasure if you let me know that